# How accurate is Google Play installs measure?

Tags: google-play-store, installation

When you look at app listing in Google Play there is "Installs" section:

[image: Installs section]

How accurate is that? What values can be found there? Does is take uninstalls into consideration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does downloads mean in Google Play store app page?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214406/what-does-downloads-mean-in-google-play-store-app-page)

Comment: Kind of yes. But not exactly. There are some valuable information but not all I want.

Comment: When using a browser on a PC or phone, "Installs" is shown. But when using the Play Store app, "Downloads" is shown.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't take uninstalls into account. It is very slow to update and based on the all-time number of individual Google accounts that installed it, NOT the devices.

That's all based on what I experienced, from the Play Console combined with Store

Possible values include:

1+

5+

(Maybe some more)

100+

500+

1k+

5k+(?)

10k+

50k+

100k+

(Maybe some more)

1m+

(Maybe some more)

1b+